# JQuery Mobile Listview trigger create scrolling

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm having trouble with jquerymobile listview. If I add li-items with javascript to the listview and trigger create to refresh the listview, the page scrolls up to the top of the listview.

Is it possible to refresh a listview and stay at the current y scrolling position?

The ul is in a div with the id List_Container.

I'm calling

```
$('#List_Container').html(content_sql_list).trigger('create');
```

Same results with

```
$('ul').listview('refresh');
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.